# MGF of Random Variables

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

The MGF of random variable W is

$$\mathbf{M}_{w}(t) = \frac{9e^2t}{9-t^2}$$

$\mathbf{E}[W]=2$

Find the Mgf of Z=3(W-2). Simplify your result.

To $\mathbf{M}_{w}(t)$ do you take $\mathbf{E}[e^t*z]$ or would you have to take $\mathbf{E}[Z]$ in terms of W?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. The definition of $M_{\mathbf Z}(t)$ is $$M_{\mathbf Z}(t) = \mathbb E[e^{t \mathbf Z}].$$ You are given $M_{\mathbf W}(t) = \mathbb E[e^{t\mathbf W}]$, and so your goal should be to express $\mathbb E[e^{t \mathbf Z}] = \mathbb E[e^{t \cdot 3(\mathbf W-2)}]$ in terms of $\mathbb E[e^{t\mathbf W}]$.

Comment: So since they are equal, would I "plug" my value of the MGF of W into the W you have in the E[e^tz] value? We know what z equals and don't we know what W equals also? Because E[W] = 2

Comment: We don't know what $W$ equals to; $W$ is a random variable. We know what $\mathbb E[e^{t\mathbf W}]$ equals to, for any $t$. So you should expand $ \mathbb E[e^{t \cdot 3(\mathbf W-2)}]$ as best you can, and whenever you see anything of the form $\mathbb E[e^{x\mathbf W}]$ for any $x$, replace it by $\frac{9e^2x}{9-x^2}$.

Comment: So we start to expand it by doing? ${E}[e^{t(3(w-2))}]=e^{3tw-6t}$ ?

Comment: so expanding it and trying to simplify I have the follow but I'm still not sure how to get tit to the next step. I have $E[e^{t(3(w-2)}]=e^{3tw}/e^{6t}$ But where do i head next? I don't see anything like the  Mw(t)

Comment: You keep dropping the expected values. $e^{3t\mathbf W}$ is a random variable; $\mathbb E[e^{3t\mathbf W}]$ is its expected value. These are different things! You should be able to express $\mathbb E[e^{3t\mathbf W}]$ in terms of the MGF of $\mathbf W$.

Comment: Wait, like this?! ${E[{e^{3tw}}]=E[e^{3t({9e^{2t}/{9-t^2}}. Then I need to keep simplifying everything? *sorry i'm not very good with getting the equations in the nice looking way*

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. $\mathbf W$ and $M_{\mathbf W}(t)$ are not the same thing! You can't replace one by the other.

Comment: I think that to properly understand what's going on you need to go back and review what random variables and expected values mean. Your question relies on a solid understanding of these, and if you don't have it, you are at risk of just moving around symbols without knowing what they are.

Comment: I keep dropping the E[x] while typing cause I am typing with a broken collar bone and it hurts. However you are deffienetly right. @MishaLarov I have one more idea and would like your input on it. Let me know if I am on the right track? There is a property I think I can use that is: $M_z(t)=E[e^{tz}]=E[e^{(t3(w-2))}]=E[e^{3tw-6t}]=e^{-6t}*E[e^{3tw}]$ I'm just kind of stumped if this will help me or not. I'm not sure on what the next step I would be able to do with this is.

Comment: You are on the right track. The key fact for the next step is that if $M_{\mathbf W}(t) = \mathbb E[e^{t\mathbf W}]$, then $M_{\mathbf W}(3t) = \mathbb E[e^{3t\mathbf W}]$.

Comment: Awesome. Now that I have the $M_w(t)$ in my equation, can I plug what we know $M_w(t)$ in and multiply it by 3? Then that should equal what $M_z(t)$ is, right? like this? $e^{-6t}*(3({9e^{2t}}/9-t^2}}) = 3*e^{-6t}*{9e^{2t}/{9-t^2}$

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is a property that relates MGFs to affine transformations.

\begin{align*}
M_{aX + b}(t)
&= \mathbb{E}[e^{t \cdot (aX + b)}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[e^{taX + bt}] \\
&= e^{bt} \mathbb{E}[e^{taX}] \\
&= e^{bt} M_{X}(at)
\end{align*}

Comment: I was just looking at this. This is what I have I'm not sure about the next step though. $M_z(t)=E[e^{tz}]=E[e^{(t3(w−2))}]=E[e^{3tw−6t}]=e^{−6t}∗E[e^{3tw}]$ which is the second to last line, to get from that to last I'm not sure how to get there.